# Building an EEZYBOTARM MK1

Tags: servo, battery

My bot arm building is complete, I'm using it with Arduino and 2 joysticks with 4 servos ( mg90s), running with the 9v battery, but still, the servos could not lift the bot arm once it is going down and the servo keeps fluctuating. It is a 3d printed bot so it is not so heavy. please help?

Comment: A little wimpy PP3 battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your device is not so heavy, a 9V battery has a maximum practical current draw in the 10s of milliamps. It's not a good choice for operating motors.

A better choice would be AA, C, D, or Lithium-Ion/Lithium-Polymer batteries, wired in series to produce the desired voltage.

Comment: how much volts AA batteries?

Comment: Nominally 1.5V per cell (each AA is one cell)

Comment: will 5, AA 1.5v each work fine?

Comment: I can't answer that for you. It depends on the specs of your servos, how long you want the device to operate on one set of batteries, etc. If you needed to get to 9V, then 5 AAs will not do it. The 1.5V per cell is the max, and as they discharge, the voltage will drop lower and lower.

Comment: The proper number of batteries depends on how your servos are powered.  You must not use the Arduino's regulator for this.  Run bare they want 4 or 5 AA's depending on their maximum voltage rating and the cell chemistry.  However 5 AA's is not reliably enough to feed an Arduino's regulator.